# Git repository URL - SSH syntax without absolute path

Tags: git, ssh

I'm running a git repository server accessible via SSH, on a custom port (let's say 12345). I have found that in this case the repository URLs need to be specified using SSH syntax:

```
git clone ssh://login@server.com:12345/absolute/path/to/repository
```

I'd like to setup it in such a way that it would be possible for users to clone repositories without specifying the **absolute** path.

```
git clone ssh://login@server.com:12345/repository.git
```

I have researched the topic and found the following options:

1. Remove the custom port from the URL and make the users add it to their `~/.ssh/config` file (a last-resort workaround rather than a solution).
2. Drop SSH and use `git-daemon` and specify its `--base-path` parameter (still a workaround...)
3. Use an utility like `gitosis` or `gitolite` - but wouldn't it be an overkill to use it for this purpose only? Gitosis is discontinued, gitolite is a quite huge piece of software...

All I want is a "prettier" SSH URL with custom port (so I can distribute the whole `git clone` command and require nothing more from the remote user). Which one of the above solutions would be the most viable in my case?

Comment: Gitolite isn't actually that big, but it's really well maintained and pretty easy to set up.  I had my doubts the first time too, but I've been happy to have it.

Answer (score 90):

If you use the alternate form of `ssh` URLs you don't need an absolute path.  For example...

```
git clone lars@myserver.example.com:repos/myrepo.git
```

...will clone repository `repos/myrepo.git` relative to my home directory, although this doesn't permit use of an alternate port.  However, you can also use `~` in either form to indicate the user's home directory, e.g.:

```
git clone ssh://login@server.com:12345/~/repository.git
```

Incidentally, despite being discontinued, `gitosis` functions quite well, and the code is both small and easy to understand.  It offers a useful set of access controls and self-service management of repositories.  I wouldn't discount it completely.

Comment: You can still set a custom port for the first example in SSH config. That's actually how I prefer to do it. I reference the remote server via an alias in git repos and set all the necessary parameters in SSH config. So if I decide to change my server configuration somehow, I just change the SSH config.

Comment: Just tried this with git version 2.7.4, and it seems only the second example works.

Comment: The first example continues to work with `git` version up through 2.9.3.  That's just part of the standard syntax.  If you're experiencing difficulties you may want to open a new question.

Comment: The slash works for me `git clone git+ssh://user@host.tld:/~/repo.git`. Thanks a lot. Actually, `git clone user@host.tld:~/repo.git` is the best way, but for some reasons I have to use `git+ssh://` scheme.

Comment: Is the alternate form actually a legal URL according to the URL spec?

Comment: The form `user@host:/repository` is not a URL.

Answer (score 6):

I do this, not exactly what you asked, but close and with prettier links:

create a path like

```
/srv/git
```

where you place you git projects

next make a symbolic link to home:

```
ln -s /srv/git $HOME
```

next you can have shorter links

```
git clone user@server:git/myproject.git
```

if you have a single project you can get rid of the git/ part in the url

```
ln -s /srv/git/myproject.git $HOME
```

next

```
git clone user@server:myproject.git
```

will work.
Of course the .git at the end of the URL comes only from creating the bare with .git in the name.
Note also that ssh:// part is not needed: the @ implies it is an ssh URL for git.

Updated: let me add a sidenote: following the most recent [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) I use now `/srv/git` as repository location.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this really deserves to be a whole answer, but I'm sick of fighting with comment-specific formatting rules.  I come to say:

I just want to add that this seems to be a version-specific change, though I'm not sure if it's client-side or server/repo-holder side: I have a `.git/config` file with lots of URLs like:

```
[remote "bob"]
    url = ssh://ME@MACHINE<strong>/~ME</strong>/repositories/REPO.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/bob/*
```

They all worked when I set them up ... in 2010, and were still working the last time I used those remotes, in 2016 or so.

Now, on version 2.18.0, those don't work, and I need to use the `:/~ME/foo` or `:/~/foo` notation. Which is to say that what you're trying to do no hasn't always been wrong.