# git remote set-url: How can I set a relative path?

Tags: git, git-remote

I know I can use `git remote set-url origin` to change the URL of a remote repo? On my Linux machine I run something like

```
git remote set-url origin ~/projects/test.git
```

but `git` always changes the relative path into an absolute one such as `/home/user/projects/test.git`.

Can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Just between us: `~/projects/test.git` isn't what's usually known as a relative path.  A relative path is more something like: `../file`, or `subdir/file`. `projects/test.git` *is* relative to `~`, but the resulting path is no less absolute.

Comment: You're right of course ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~` is probably expanded by your shell in that command (for example, if you are using bash see 'tilde expansion' in http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html).

You might get what you want by quoting the url with single quotes like this: `git remote set-url origin '~/projects/test.git'`.

**Edit**: I don't think having a tilde path as a remote is a good idea though. I'm not sure how the expansion is made. As mentioned in the comments, git is a mix of c programs and bash scripts. This could make the tilde expansion fail under certain command and work for others.

Comment: You might be able to actually get the config parameter set to include the tilde that way, but I'm not entirely sure `git` will know what to do with it after that - does `git` do tilde-expansion?

Comment: @twalberg I'm not sure who does the expansion... it might be a shell script called by the git command doing it. It does work under cygwin though.

Comment: Since git is a mixture of shell script and compiled binaries, I would want to do some extensive testing to make sure that all the tools (at least the ones I need on a regular basis) work well with the tilde syntax. It's quite possible that `git` is ok with it, though.

Comment: I tried it with double quotes and it works, thanks for pointing it out.  

BTW, the reason why I need this is because I share some repositories between different machines. They all have different usernames, but the same directory structure inside the user's home directory.

Comment: This post confirms (or at least suggests) the same, to use `~` -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/14349254/1277343

Answer (score 0):

It’s simply is because `~` is shorthand that expands to the *absolute* path of the current user’s home directory.