# connect to GIT repository gives error peer certificate invalid

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssl-certificate

My company has moved to a new GITHUB repository. On my Linux development server I am trying to connect to the new git repository in order to clone it. I have a deployment tool that gets the software from the GIT repository and deploy it automatically.

However, my new connection to the new repository does not work

```
$ git clone https://githubxxxxx.com/xxxxxxx/myrepo.git
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://githubxxxxx.com/xxxxxxx/myrepo.git/': Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.
```

I guess I have done everything that I suppose to:

- I created a new key for SSH
- I stored the key in the GIT repository

I did the same procedure for my laptop and there it worked.

If I change the global property of sslVerify

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

Then I am able to connect and clone, but every time then I would have to put the user and password, which is non sense.

Does anyone know if I miss any step here ? Is there any other global variable that I have to set ?

If I do a `ssh -v` to the repository, I see that I can authenticate.

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ftpfdm/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to githubxxxxx.com (via proxy).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: proc
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi x329097! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to githubxxxxx.com closed.
```

**Update**

If I try by ssh , I got connection close by remote host

```
$ git clone ssh://githubxxxxx.com:mygroup/myrepo.git
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**New Update**

This works instead. Does anyone know why it works this way and not with `ssh://`, when actually is a cloning by ssh. I was about to post the solution as answer, but I think it is not right, as I have no idea why this way works.

```
git clone git@githubxxxxx.com:group/myrepo.git
```

Comment: When you connect via `https://` you are NOT connecting via SSH. Switch your url to the ssh one: `ssh://git@…`

Comment: @knittl, if I do that, I got connection refused. I tried

Comment: Try `git@github…:group/project.git` (the `:` after the host part is important) GitHub has options to generate those URLs for you

Comment: I updated the question. If I try your method, I got the new error

Comment: I found the error. It is without the `ssh://`. However, I don't know why.

Comment: With the `ssh://` schema, it should be `ssh://user@host/path/to/repository.git`

Comment: @knittl, it does not work either. Actually, I updated the question because I have no idea why the only way it works is : `git clone git@githubxxxxx.com:group/myrepo.git`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14348874/112968

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.

This is purely an HTTPS issue and has nothing to do with SSH.

You need to do:

- [get the certificate of your remote GitHub server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52553687/6309)
- save it as a file `/home/<me>/ghe.pem` (replace `<me>` by your user login)
- reference it with:

  ```
  git config --global http."https://githubxxxxx.com/".sslcainfo ${HOME}/ghe.pem
  ```

If you are using an SSH URL, you always need to use the remote user '`git`', which is why `git@githubxxxxx.com:group/myrepo.git` works.